# PostgreSQL Trigger insert records to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql-9.3

I have to solve a little big problem. I will try to show you all information so you can help me.

Amazon Server #1: ubuntu-raring-13.04-amd64-server with postgreSQL DB version 9.3

Amazon Server #2: MS Windows Server 2012 Standard with MS SQL Server 2012

I'm runnig an application on Server #1 that get a lot of records by minute and write them into a table,  I have to send some of them (only one client) to a Foreing table in Server #2. 
The job in Server #1, I will prefer, to be done after insert the record so I can have the id of this record in Foreing Table on Server #1 DB. 
Because I have to send them by WS once a minute I suppose need to do this with a TRIGGER. 
I never did something like this, so Im thinking to do is using postgres_fdw and follow this steps:

a) On Server #1
  1) Install the postgres_fdw extension using CREATE EXTENSION.
  2) Create a foreign server object, using CREATE SERVER.
  3) Create a user mapping, using CREATE USER MAPPING.
  4) Create a foreign table, using CREATE FOREIGN TABLE.

b) On Server #2
  1) Create the table using the same properties than the one used on Server #1

C) Create a Function for the TRIGGER that insert the record on the foreing table.
D) Create a TRIGGER Procedure to TABLE.

I would like to know if Im in the right way or I missing something? Sorry for  my English, Thank you.

Comment: `postgres_fdw` won't do you any good for connecting to MS SQL Server. You'll need to use a foreign data wrapper for SQL Server. Personally I'd probably use a trigger queue table and a simple script to copy the new records.

Comment: Hi Craig, thank for answer. Would you please, write an esquematic for me so I can understand the idea?